# Pandas dataframe has JSON data in column, want to move all data in column to new dataframe

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame with a column with string data formatted similar to JSON. Each row of the DataFrame represents an article or book, and the column in question contains information on every author credited for that work. I do not know what the maximum number of authors listed for a work is. Please see an example cell from the column below.

```
[{'author_position': 'first', 'author': {'id': 'https://openalex.org/A5024137267', 'display_name': 'David S. Lee', 'orcid': 'https://orcid.org/0000-0002-5984-8861'}, 'institutions': [], 'countries': [], 'is_corresponding': False, 'raw_author_name': 'Lee, David S.', 'raw_affiliation_string': '', 'raw_affiliation_strings': []}, {'author_position': 'middle', 'author': {'id': 'https://openalex.org/A5024266498', 'display_name': 'G.M. Swift', 'orcid': None}, 'institutions': [], 'countries': [], 'is_corresponding': False, 'raw_author_name': 'Swift, Gary', 'raw_affiliation_string': '', 'raw_affiliation_strings': []}, {'author_position': 'last', 'author': {'id': 'https://openalex.org/A5041342112', 'display_name': 'Michael Wirthlin', 'orcid': 'https://orcid.org/0000-0003-0328-6713'}, 'institutions': [], 'countries': [], 'is_corresponding': False, 'raw_author_name': 'Wirthlin, Michael', 'raw_affiliation_string': '', 'raw_affiliation_strings': []}]
```

EDIT: the data types for the column is listed below as well

```
>>> print(df["authorships"].head)
<bound method NDFrame.head of 3089     [{'author_position': 'first', 'author': {'id':...
42144    [{'author_position': 'first', 'author': {'id':...
Name: authorships, dtype: object>


>>> print(type(df["authorships"].iloc[0]))
<class 'str'>
```

I wish to convert the contents of this column into a DataFrame where each row represents an author and all the information nested under "author" (such as "id", "display_name", etc.) are the columns. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

I have tried using various tools from the json package and the pandas package, such as `pandas.json_normalize` and `json.loads`, but I am new to python and haven't had any luck as every post I've attempted to implement has resulted in an error of some kind.

Answer (score 1):

The data in your column appears to be a long `str` that has a structure similar to a `list` with `str` and `dict` values.

This isn't JSON, as JSON uses doubles quotes (`"`) and not single quotes (`'`). So one option is to parse this as Python objects using something like [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

After you parse the data, you'll be left with a row containing a `list`, which you can `.explode` into multiple rows, with each row containing data of a single author. Then you can use `.apply` to get the data from `author` and expand it into columns `id`, `display_name` and `orcid`.

Let's assume this dataframe is similar to the one you have:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "authorships": """[
            {
                "author_position": "first",
                "author": {
                    "id": "https://openalex.org/A5024137267",
                    "display_name": "David S. Lee",
                    "orcid": "https://orcid.org/0000-0002-5984-8861",
                },
                "institutions": [],
                "countries": [],
                "is_corresponding": False,
                "raw_author_name": "Lee, David S.",
                "raw_affiliation_string": "",
                "raw_affiliation_strings": [],
            },
            {
                "author_position": "middle",
                "author": {
                    "id": "https://openalex.org/A5024266498",
                    "display_name": "G.M. Swift",
                    "orcid": None,
                },
                "institutions": [],
                "countries": [],
                "is_corresponding": False,
                "raw_author_name": "Swift, Gary",
                "raw_affiliation_string": "",
                "raw_affiliation_strings": [],
            },
            {
                "author_position": "last",
                "author": {
                    "id": "https://openalex.org/A5041342112",
                    "display_name": "Michael Wirthlin",
                    "orcid": "https://orcid.org/0000-0003-0328-6713",
                },
                "institutions": [],
                "countries": [],
                "is_corresponding": False,
                "raw_author_name": "Wirthlin, Michael",
                "raw_affiliation_string": "",
                "raw_affiliation_strings": [],
            },
        ]"""
    },
    index=[0],
)
```

You can then do the following:

```
import ast

# Parse the `str` values and explode the data in different columns
df["authorships"] = df["authorships"].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x))
df = df.explode("authorships").reset_index(drop=True)

# Create the new columns with data from `author`
df[["id", "display_name", "orcid"]] = df.apply(
    lambda x: x["authorships"]["author"].values(), axis=1, result_type="expand"
)
```

```
                                         authorships                                id      display_name                                  orcid
0  {'author_position': 'first', 'author': {'id': ...  https://openalex.org/A5024137267      David S. Lee  https://orcid.org/0000-0002-5984-8861
1  {'author_position': 'middle', 'author': {'id':...  https://openalex.org/A5024266498        G.M. Swift                                   None
2  {'author_position': 'last', 'author': {'id': '...  https://openalex.org/A5041342112  Michael Wirthlin  https://orcid.org/0000-0003-0328-6713
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply! The column is called "authorships" in the original data, and when I plugged that in to the code in question I get the following error: 
"TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'"

The code I used was: df[["id", "display_name", "orcid"]] = df.apply(lambda x: x['authorships']['author'].values(), axis=1)

Comment: @WildcatPhD this suggests the data in your column is of type `str`, which is different from what is in your question. Can you edit the question and update it with (1) the result of `print(df["authorships"].head)` and (2) the result of `print(type(df["authorships"].iloc[0]))`?

Comment: I have edited the post as you suggested. Hopefully this proves helpful!